# Which object holds the "follow" details?

Tags: chatter, feeditem, follow, entitysubscription

I am wondering which object holds the details of "follow". When i click the follow link in Account detail page I understand we can follow the record changes. Based on that understanding i have searched the salesforce schema for the object which might have stored the "follow" details but i did not find a one. Where could i find the details of the follow of a record and which object holds that detail? Please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The object that you are looking for is called `EntitySubscription`.

**From the documentation**

> Represents a subscription for a user following a record or another
> user. A user can subscribe to a record or to another user.

You can see the full documentation using the link below.

[https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_entitysubscription.htm)

You could also check out the Chatter cheat sheet as it is covered in that as well

http://media.developerforce.com/cheatsheets/SF_chatter_4Pg_HR.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can also get that information via the ConnectAPI - details [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_Chatter_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_Chatter_getFollowers)

This method returns a 'followerpage' that lets you get at the followers for a specific page:

ConnectApi.FollowerPage accountfollowers = ConnectAPI.Chatter.getFollowers(String communityId, String recordId)

e.g. :

```
ConnectApi.FollowerPage accountfollowers = ConnectAPI.Chatter.getFollowers(null, '001R000000pesmV');
for (ConnectAPI.Subscription s: accountfollowers.followers ) {
    system.debug(s.Subscriber); //details about follower
    system.debug(s.Subscriber.Id); //User Id
    system.debug(s.Subscriber.Name); //User Id

}
```